# Julia: function inside a struct and method constructor

Tags: struct, julia

What is the correct way to store a function in a struct constructor? And retrieve it? And change its parameters?

I wrote some code back in version 0.4 to 0.5, which unsurprisingly no longer works. In words: I have a `struct-cum-method` named Model in which I define parameters and functional forms. And a similarly structured Solution in which I solve instances of the model. My purpose is to make multiple simulations of the model for different sets of parameters and functional forms. The code below is part of a module inside a package. I don't have a good handle on how to deal with the function type in `Julia 1.6` (something like the code below used to work).

```
# Non-Parametric version of struct + outer method constructor
# Model parameters and functions
struct Model
    f::Function
    p::Float64
    n::Int64
end
function Model(; 
    f::Function = x -> x + p,
    p::Float64 = 2.0,
    n::Int64 = 4
    )
    Model(f, p, n)
end
```

This is the output of `Model()`:

```
julia> m = Model()
Model(var"#2#4"(), 2.0, 4)

julia> Model(p = 1.0)
Model(var"#3#5"(), 1.0, 4)

julia> m.f
#2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> m.p
2.0

julia> m.n
4

julia> Model(f = x -> x - p)
Model(var"#15#16"(), 2.0, 4)


julia> m.f(1.0)
ERROR: UndefVarError: p not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] (::var"#2#4")(x::Float64)
   @ Main ./REPL[2]:2
 [2] top-level scope
   @ REPL[4]:1
```

I'd be grateful for pointers on where the code goes wrong and how to fix it. If at all recommended, I'd like a parametric struct.

Comment: I recommend against using the `Function` type, really ever. I would instead just leave your type parameter `Objective` unconstrained. Any type can support function calls, not just `Function`. e.g. `Float64` is a function.

Comment: Hi Gus. Feel free to post an answer. I'm starting to think that the function should not be inside the struct, as you say. How would you write this minimal example? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `Base.@kwdef` or an `@with_kw` equivalent from the `Parameters` package (I prefer the latter since it provides nicer formatting for the console)

```
Base.@kwdef struct Model
    p::Float64 = 2.0
    n::Int64 = 4
    f::Function = x -> x + p
end
```

This now can be used such as:

```
julia> Model(p=7).f(11)
18
```

Regarding solution you should separate the actual solution structure from the constructor. Hence you will have a `function solve(m::Model)` (or `solve!` if `m` is mutated in the process) that should yields a `Solution` object.

For creating the `Solution` object use the same pattern as above.

Comment: Thanks Przemyslaw. I wonder: 1. So ``Base.@kwdef`` is not exported, does it mean there's another, preferred way to do this? Or should I prefer the ``@with_kw`` solution? 2. With this approach, you did not break down the construction into the usual two steps ``struct`` and ``method``, but I could still have two steps, right?

Comment: Also, ``Model(p=7).f(11)`` works, but ``Model(f=x->x+2*p).f(11)`` does not work. Is there a way to redefine ``f``?

Comment: 1. I use `@with_kw` in the future `Base.@kwdef` will probably get exported. 2. Yes you can build as many constructors as you want. 3. Julia is not object oriented language so there are no elegant ways to reference `this`/`self` object.

Comment: There are possible workarounds but they will always result in a very ugly API. Hence perhaps the best thing would be to have `f(m::Model)` defined outside of the model. One possible approach: https://github.com/ipod825/OOPMacro.jl

Comment: I have just realized that the order inside ``struct Model`` matters! You have placed the function after the parameter, if you place it before (as I had it in my question), it won't work!